# Post was removed after I flagged it. How to know if I flagged correctly?

Tags: discussion, flags, flag-weight

As I saw an answer which was an offensive comment on one of our peer, I flagged it as offensive, and just 5 minutes after the user (or a moderator) removed that answer. How can I know if I flagged the answer correctly or not?

Comment: It matters if it was an *answer* or a *comment* that you flagged—you're treating them like one in the same here. Comment flags are not displayed in your flagging history (although they do have a minor effect on your flag weight).

Comment: I guess it was an answer containing an offensive phrase about another user.

Comment: @Cody Gray It was an answer which i flagged

Comment: yes @kiamlaluno exactly

Comment: Massive edit war. @Devjosh Please be more specific the next time. "Answer" vs "Comment" makes a huge difference.

Comment: @slhck  i edited the question heading

Comment: Devjosh was specific, as he said, "I saw an answer." If the answer was commenting about a user, then the answer contained a comment about that user, which is a remark expressing an opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment flags aren't trackable (from your point of view).

If you want, I can tell you if comment was deleted, if you give me link to that question/answer.

But if you really think it was offensive, there's nothing wrong with flagging

Comment: No you can't. Only moderators can see deleted comments. But we just established in the comments that this is a deleted *answer*. So yes, any 10k users can see those.

Comment: But when I come to question and I do not see any offensive comment, I think I can say that it was deleted, probably by moderator. BTW I think OP saw OFFENSIVE COMMENT IN AN ANSWER, not offensive comment :)

Comment: @genesis-φ i personally felt it offensive not on me but on one of our peer so i flagged but it is not necessary that my point of view will match with the persons who validate the flags :)

Comment: yes @genesis it was an answer which used indecent language

Comment: @Dev: Could you give link to question where flagged answer was?

Comment: yes of course but that may be of no use because the answer i flagged is no more there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119308/check-that-element-is-in-dom-or-not-with-jquery/7119371#7119371

Comment: `Maybe you'll find it out if you wake up and become flushed down the loo ^^, or you try some of the other examples posted here!` deleted by owner 1 hour ago

Comment: @ genesis-φ yes it is the same post

Comment: @Devjosh: so it's deleted by its autor :)

Answer (score 4):

When you click on the flag weight in your user profile, you are taken to a page showing the history of your flags; each flag is shown as in the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

(The question shown as second item had another flag that has been considered valid; that is the reason the question has been deleted.)

If you don't read "valid," "invalid," or "disputed," then the flag is still pending, which means nobody has reviewed the flag.
Consider that, for old flags, there are no records about the flag being valid or not, as before that information was not retained; this doesn't seem your case, but if you are looking for some old flags, you could notice there is no indication of the flag validity, even though the flag has been already considered valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

A few points that come to my mind. If it was an answer you flagged:

- If your flag is still listed as *pending*, it probably wasn't a moderator who deleted the post.
- Moderators can still see deleted posts, no matter who deleted them, so they'll be able to evaluate if you flagged correctly.
- Since you yourself can't see the post anymore, right now there's no way to check if you should have been more careful in flagging.

But there's not much to worry about, the worst that could happen would be your flag weight decreasing by a few points. It's not like anyone is going to send riders in the night wearing white hoodies and carrying torches.

If it was a comment you flagged, as soon as a certain number of flags accumulate, comments are deleted automatically. As far as I remember, comment flags don't affect your flag weight.

One way or another, I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: 10k users can see answers too.

Comment: ok @takrl so on thing is definite now that the user himself rolled back the answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this question. What does "correctly" mean here? Are you concerned that you flagged improperly in the first instance?

A moderator agreed with your flag and removed the post: that's the only measure of "correct" that really exists, and since that's what's happened, that means your flag was "correct". Otherwise nothing would have happened. No?

---

#### Edit

Ah, yes, the owner could have deleted it too.

So, is this question really *"How can I find out who removed an answer?"*

If so, the answer is: *when you have [enough rep (10k+)](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools), you can see deleted answers and information about who deleted them.*

Comment: that was not my question tomalak i request you to read the question one more time please

Comment: Request denied. If that was not your question then I don't know wtf was.

Comment: The question is, using other words, "How can I know if my flag was considered valid or not?"

Comment: @kiamlaluno: And that's no more clear than before. You're probably going to need more than one sentence. What do you mean by "valid"? If your flag were not valid, then surely the post would not have been removed by a moderator. Is that not the _definition_ of when a flag is "valid"?

Comment: Well, who posted the answer could have deleted it, and in that case the flag is probably not marked as valid, as no action as been taken from a moderator; what @Devjosh is asking is how to know if his flag is considered valid or not. In this context, "valid flag" has a specific meaning, as that is the phrase used in the flag history.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Ah, that's true. It could have been owned-removed rather than moderator-removed. Is that what is being asked here?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal i am sorry but you still not getting actual question as you appended something to your answer not at all useful at least for me regarding this question

Comment: @Devjosh: I disagree. I believe that I have isolated the core of your question. You want to know whether a flag was "valid", and you know that the answer was deleted. The flag was "valid" if the answer was deleted by a moderator rather than a user. And you know whether the answer was deleted by a moderator rather than a user when you have enough rep to see this information. // If this is not correct, please explain _in detail_ how so.

Comment: @Cody: Thanks for that. I couldn't be bothered to look it up;)